# Ambiguous occurrence ‘stdout’

Tags: haskell, testing, haskell-stack, ambiguous, doctest

I've been trying to put on unit testing via `doctest`. Getting error:

```
hs-procr-0.1.0.0: test (suite: hs-procr-test)

Progress: 1/2
<interactive>:5:14: error:
Ambiguous occurrence ‘stdout’
It could refer to either ‘Turtle.stdout’,
                         imported from ‘Turtle’ at app/Main.hs:7:1-13
                         (and originally defined in ‘Turtle.Prelude’)
                      or ‘System.IO.stdout’,
                         imported from ‘System.IO’
                         (and originally defined in ‘GHC.IO.Handle.FD’)
```

I've got no idea why; all my `*.hs` files got

```
import System.IO hiding (FilePath, stdout, stderr)
```

`package.yaml`:

```
...
tests:
  hs-procr-test:
    main:                Spec.hs
    source-dirs:         test
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - hs-procr
```

`Spec.hs`:

```
module Main (main) where

import Test.DocTest
import System.IO hiding (FilePath, stdout, stderr)

main :: IO ()
main = doctest [ "app/Main.hs"
               ]
```

I use `stack`, there is no *.cabal file. What have I missed?

`Main.hs`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main ( main
            , strStripNumbers
            ) where

import Lib
import Turtle
import Prelude hiding (FilePath)
import System.IO hiding (FilePath, stdout, stderr)
import Text.Regex.TDFA
...
```

Comment: Could you show the main.hs file I guess you are not hiding stdout there - maybe you have a `import System.IO as Something` instead of `import qualified ..` there. Also  try `stack clean` just to make sure.

Comment: Main.hs added. Looks like everything is taken care of. Besides, non-testing builds are successful.

Comment: "imported from ‘Turtle’ at app/Main.hs:7:1-13" You are also importing `stdout` from `Turtle`.

Comment: What's wrong with that? It builds and runs. `$ stack test` is the problem.

Comment: At a guess: doctest has a list of default imports that it makes sure is available when running a doctest, and this is causing the conflict. If so you may need to qualify all mentions of conflicting imports (and possibly qualify all imports of conflicting names, depending on exactly what's going on here). Luckily this isn't so terrible if you give nice short names to your imported modules with `as`.

Comment: If you are right, it is not nice at all. Compilers shouldn't do such things.

Comment: @AlexeyOrlov Not sure what that means. 1. The compiler isn't at fault here if doctest is explicitly requesting additional imports. 2. Every compiler I know of silently brings a few things into scope, and it would be extremely painful if they didn't. So in my view, compilers *should* do such things and also your problem is *not* the result of a compiler doing such things.

Comment: I added `import Turtle hiding (stdout, stderr)` to `Main.hs`. So far so good.